# Completely Blank Google Terrain Map?

Tags: google-maps, terrain

I need a completely blank Google Maps Terrain map. I know how to use the API tool, however, I can't get rid of the green, grey, and white filled polygons that represent park lands and urban areas.

I just want the Terrain. Nothing else.

Suggestions? I've searched extensively, and no answers are forthcoming.

DZ

Comment: Have a look at styled maps:-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styled_map_wizard
You can turn different features off. I haven't tried it enough to give a definitive answer.